# Show that Mergelyan's theorem cannot extend to the case in which $S^2-K$ has infinitely many components.

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an exercise in W. Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.

> For $n=1,2,\ldots$, let $D_n=D(\alpha_n;r_n)$ be disjoint open discs in (the unit open disk) $U$ whose union $V$ is dense in $U$, such that $\sum_nr_n<\infty$. Put $K=\bar U-V$. Let $\Gamma$ and $\gamma_n$ be the paths
>   $$\Gamma(t)=e^{it},\quad \gamma_n(t)=\alpha_n+r_ne^{it},\quad 0\le t\le2\pi,$$
>   and define 
>   $$L(f)=\int_\Gamma f(z)\mathrm{d}z-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{\gamma_n}f(z)\mathrm{d}z.\quad(f\in C(K))$$
>   Prove that (a) $L$ is a bounded linear functional on $C(K)$; (b) $L(R)=0$ for every rational function $R$ whose poles are outside $K$; (c) there exists an $f\in C(K)$ for which $L(f)\ne0$.

My first question is: Why does these disks $D_n$ exist? Suppose they do exist. I can prove (a) and (b). But how can I prove part (c)?

I'm really confused. Should I construct the disks $D_n$ / the function $f$ explicitly or just show the existence?

Can anyone give some advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I take $f(t)=1$ then I get $L(f)=2\pi(1-\sum_n r_n)$. Why this is zero? Did you mean $\int_\Gamma f(z)\,dz$?

Comment: @A.G. Yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I construct the disks $D_n$ / the function $f$ explicitly or just show the existence?

Showing the existence of $f$ suffices. But often the easiest way to show existence is giving an explicit example. As for the sequence of disks, I think an *explicit* construction is way beyond the scope of the exercise (if at all possible), but one can show that such a sequence exists.

Take your favourite countable dense subset of the open unit disk - for example the set of points with rational real and imaginary part - and enumerate it $\{ p_k : k \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}\}$. Let $K_0 = \varnothing$ and $m_0 = 0$. For every $k \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, if $p_k \in K_{k-1}$, set $K_k = K_{k-1}$ and $m_k = m_{k-1}$. Otherwise choose a radius $0 < r < \frac{1}{2k^2}$ such that $\overline{D(p_k;r)} \subset U\setminus K_{k-1}$ and set $m_k = m_{k-1}+1$, $\alpha_{m_k} = p_k$, $r_{m_k} = r$ and $K_k = K_{k-1} \cup \overline{D(p_k;r)}$.

By construction, each $K_k$ is a compact subset of $U$, so there are $m > k$ with $p_m \notin K_k$, hence you get an infinite sequence of disjoint disks. Since for each $k$ we have $p_k \in K_k$, and hence $p_k \in \overline{D(\alpha_j;r_j)}$ for some $j \leqslant k$, the closure of the union $V$ of the open disks contains a dense subset of $U$, hence $V$ is dense in $U$. The upper bound on the chosen radii forces $\sum r_n < +\infty$.

Having shown the existence of such disks, we note that by the standard estimate we have

$$\biggl\lvert\int_{\lvert z-a \rvert = r} f(z)\,dz\biggr\rvert \leqslant 2\pi r\cdot \lVert f\rVert_\infty$$

and hence

$$\lvert L(f)\rvert \leqslant 2\pi \Biggl(1 + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty r_n\Biggr)\cdot \lVert f\rVert_\infty,$$

so $L$ is continuous.

If $R$ is a rational function whose poles lie outside $K$, then each pole of $R$ lies either outside the closed unit disk or in exactly one of the disks $D_n$. The poles outside the closed unit disk don't contribute to $L(R)$ since neither $\Gamma$ nor any $\gamma_n$ winds around these poles, and for the poles in $D_m$, only $\gamma_m$ and $\Gamma$ wind around these poles, both with winding number $1$, so the integrals cancel for the principal part of $R$ in these poles. The partial fraction decomposition of $R$ thus shows $L(R) = 0$.

For the last part, a simple continuous function whose integral over circles doesn't vanish is the conjugation. We have

$$\int_{\lvert z-a\rvert = r} \overline{z}\,dz = 2\pi ir^2,$$

so

$$L(z \mapsto \overline{z}) = 2\pi i \Biggl(1 - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty r_n^2\Biggr).$$

In the construction above, it is easily seen that $\sum r_n^2 < 1$, so $f(z) = \overline{z}$ works.

If it were possible to choose the radii such that $\sum r_n^2 = 1$<sup>(1)</sup>, then $K$ would be a null set, and by the [Hartogs-Rosenthal theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs%E2%80%93Rosenthal_theorem) (thanks to [A.G.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/253273/a-g) for pointing it out), every continuous function on $K$ would be a uniform limit of rational functions, so then $L(f) = 0$ for all $f\in C(K)$. But - thanks again to [A.G.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/253273/a-g) for digging up the reference - if one has a sequence of disjoint disks in $U$ such that $\sum r_n^2 = 1$, then it follows that $\sum r_n = +\infty$, so under the constraints of the exercise we have $\sum r_n^2 < 1$. A proof of this using approximation theory for holomorphic functions is contained in Mergelyan's 1952 paper<sup>(2)</sup>, and an elementary proof of a generalisation is in [Oscar Wesler's 1960 paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1960-011-02/S0002-9939-1960-0112078-8/S0002-9939-1960-0112078-8.pdf).

---

<sup>(1)</sup> We have $\sum r_n^2 \leqslant 1$ since $V$ has measure $\pi \sum r_n^2$ as a disjoint union of disks, and since $V \subset U$, that measure is bounded by $\pi$.

<sup>(2)</sup> S. N. Mergelyan, *Uniform approximations to functions of a complex variable*, Uspehi Mat. Nauk. vol. 7 (1952) pp. 31-122; Amer. Math. Soc. Transi, no. 101 (1954) p. 21.

Comment: Is $\sum r_n^2>1$ never possible for such a cover? Just don't see a simple explanation for that.

Comment: We have a disjoint sequence of measurable subsets of the unit disk, so $\sum \lambda(D_n) \leqslant \lambda(U)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. That is $\sum r_n^2 \leqslant 1$.

Comment: Nice. I didn't think about $\bar{z}$ whatsoever.

Comment: @EclipseSun The construction is called *Swiss cheese set* in honor of its inventor, the Swiss mathematician Alice Roth. See, for example, the book of Gamelin, "Complex Analysis", 2001, p. 344-345.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, I still kind of puzzled about the last sentence. If $\sum r_n^2=1$ then the measure of $K$ is zero. Isn't that the case when the [Hartogs-Rosenthal theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs%E2%80%93Rosenthal_theorem) tells us that any continuous $f$ can be approximated uniformly by rationals? So $0=L(f_n)\to L(f)=0$ and a counterexample would be impossible.

Comment: @A.G. Good point. So it must be impossible to choose the radii so that $\sum r_n^2 = 1$. Hrrmphh that looks like more measure theory than I like on a Sunday morning.

Comment: @DanielFischer After some googling it turns out that if $\sum r_n^2=1$ then for such radii $\sum r_n=+\infty$ [(c) Oscar Wesler, 1960.](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1960-011-02/S0002-9939-1960-0112078-8/S0002-9939-1960-0112078-8.pdf) Interesting! But it feels a bit too much for an exercise though... It was no Google that time :)

Comment: @A.G. Awesome, thanks. How did you manage to find that? I wouldn't know what to google for.

Comment: @DanielFischer I looked for "Swiss cheese set" first and in one link it was stated that the sum of radii was infinite and given the reference to Wesler's paper. The first page with some historical facts about Borel and Denjoy is an interesting reading there.

Comment: @A.G. Indeed an interesting read. The proof is astonishingly simple - if one has the right idea (which is decidedly nontrivial).